# Laravel relationship eager loading limiting all results instead of model specific

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a nested relationship like:

`Model One` has many `Model Twos` which has many `Model Threes`.

The aim is to get all `Model Ones` and all their `Model Twos` and for the each of the `Model Twos` only get the latest `Model Three`.

I have tried:

```php
return ModelOne::with(['modelTwos.latestModelThree'])
    ->paginate();
```

But this is only giving the `Model Three` for the last `Model Two` of the last `Model One`.

All other `Model Twos` have no `Model Three` in the response.

The method for `latestModelThree` on the `Model Two` class is:

```php
public function latestModelThree()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelThree::class)
            ->latest()
            ->limit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Elias Soares does work but causes major performance issues with large datasets.

A more performant solution is to use this package: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 1):

Changing `larestModelThree()` relationship to `hasOne()` and removing the limit should do the trick:

```
public function latestModelThree()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ModelThree::class)
            ->latest();
    }
```

It's a little hacky, and don't solve the problem if you need N items of that relationship instead of a single item, but, solves your problem.

Comment: While this does work it causes major performance issues when dealing with a lot of Model Three's